# 'ID' is inaccessible due to 'internal' protection level

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift-data

I have a subTaskList containing some subTasks. I want the newly added subTask can be focused automatically. But it shows the error when I write `@FocusState var focusedId: SubTask.ID?` in The SubTaskListView.swift. I use the same expression in the SubTaskRowView.swift, and it works. Why is that?

```swift
// SubTaskListView.swift
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

struct SubTaskList: View {
    @State private var selection: SubTask?
    @Query var subTasks: [SubTask]
    
    @FocusState var focusedId: SubTask.ID? // shows error: 'ID' is inaccessible due to 'internal' protection level
    
    
    init(for task: Task) {
        let id = task.id
        self._subTasks = Query(filter: #Predicate {
            $0.task?.id == id
        })
    }
    var body: some View {
        ForEach(subTasks) { subTask in
            SubTaskRow(subTask: subTask, focusedId: _focusedId)
                .tag(selection)
        }
        .onChange(of: subTasks.count) { (old, new) in
            if new < old {
                return
            }
            guard let lastSubTask = subTasks.last else {
                return
            }
            focusedId = lastSubTask.id
            selection = lastSubTask
        }
    }
}
```

```swift
// SubTaskRowView.swift
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

struct SubTaskRow: View {
    @Bindable var subTask: SubTask
    @FocusState var focusedId: SubTask.ID? // it works fine. no error shows.
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Image(systemName: "circle")
            TextField("", text: $subTask.name)
                .textFieldStyle(.plain)
                .focused($focusedId, equals: subTask.id)
        }
    }
}
```

SubTask.swift

```swift
    @Model
    final public class SubTask {
        @Attribute(.unique, originalName: "id") public var id: UUID
        @Attribute(originalName: "created_at") var createdAt: Date
        @Attribute(originalName: "updated_at") var updatedAt: Date
        @Attribute(originalName: "name") var name: String
        
        @Attribute(originalName: "task") var task: Task?

        init(id: UUID, createdAt: Date, updatedAt: Date, name: String) {
            self.id = id
            self.createdAt = createdAt
            self.updatedAt = updatedAt
            self.name = name
        }

        convenience init(name: String) {
            self.init(id: UUID(), createdAt: Date.now, updatedAt: Date.now, name: name)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is SubTaskListView.swift in a different module from the rest of your code?

Comment: The type `SubTask.ID` (also watch out it's capitalized) is not defined in the code you show. So whatever you point to in `SubTaskRow` may not be what you think. Right-click on `ID` and choose 'Jump to Definition' to see where it takes you.

Comment: The macro @Model will make the class conform to PersistentModel which extends Identifiable so the class already have an id property that is overridden/replaced here but with a different type and this seems to sometimes confuse the compiler.

Comment: Ok, I didn't know that. So probably @Tony should drop `@Attribute(.unique, originalName: "id") public var id: UUID` to avoid further confusion?

Comment: @soundflix Yes, I don't really see the point of having your own id property unless perhaps if it comes from an external source so you need it for future matching against external data.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to change this:

```
@FocusState var focusedId: SubTask.ID?
```

to this:

```
@FocusState var focusedId: UUID?
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually this is caused by acting upon a class whose atributes are not public.

```
class myclass  
{  int i;   
   string c }
```

instead of

```
{ public int i;  
  public string c }
```

I'm coding in a different language than you do but it's still likely to be similar.

Comment: Thanks! I just change `@FocusState var focusedId: SubTask.ID?` to `@FocusState var focusedId: UUID?` and it works!

Comment: @TonyCheng either post that as an answer or delete the whole question since you obviously has found a solution yourself.